# How to disable stories (user created content) in assassin's creed odyssey?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

I'm pretty tired of the blue exclamation points all over my map - they are signs for so called stories (user made side quests) in assassin's creed odyssey. How can I disable them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable stories go to Settings -> Gameplay and turn there the Story Creator Mode off.